# CSS Dropdown Menu - Want to Restrict Top Level Separate from 2nd Level

Tags: css, menu, rollover

The horizontal space on websites is more limited than the vertical space. With that in mind, I have kept the top level links on a navigation bar to single words or very short phrases. The second level is more flexible. (Of course there is no third level to avoid accessibility issues.)

I would like each

in the top level to be auto, that is to fit the size of the top level text, without expanding to fit the dropdown when the mouse rolls over it. Right now, it's doing a jumping act! If I sent the width for li to auto and the width for li li to 200px. The top expands to fit the rollover.

I have fixed this in other situations by setting all the top level

to an exact width, but I don't want that here.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Here is the code to date ...

```
/* ********* SIDEBAR FOR MAIN MENU ********* */

.well 
{
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: transparent; /* #f5f5f5; */
} /* 10/8/14 Nora moved from below 
        - Nora changed color
  */

.well h3
{
    display: none;
} /* 10/8/14 Nora added to hide menu title */

.well li
{
    float: right;
    width: auto;
} /* 10/8/14 Nora added to line navigation horizontally */

.well li
{
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #005580;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added to format links 
     10/13/14 Nora added border to keep spacing same with items with and without border
  */

.well li a
{
    color: #2B2D30;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
} /* 10/8/14 Nora added from 2.5 site */

.well ul.nav li a:hover
{
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 3px solid #8CBD2E;
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added to remove background and add in green line */

.well li.current a
{
    color: #900;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added from 2.5 theme */

/* ***** SECOND LEVEL OF NAVIGATION ***** */

.well li.parent:hover ul
{
    width: 285px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added to format rollover menu 
     10/20/14 Nora added float none for a vertical rollover menu - the first layer makes them go horizontal
     10/24/14 Nora moved the shadow off the li and onto the ul
  */

.well li ul li
{
    display: none;
    width: 275px;
} /* 10/10/14 Nora added to hide rollover menu 
     10/29/14 Nora adjusted size from 290
  */

.well li.parent:hover ul li
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    padding: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
    float: none;
    background: #fff url(../../../images/LogosIcons/NavigationShadow.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added to format rollover menu 
     10/20/14 Nora added float none for a vertical rollover menu - the first layer makes them go horizontal
     10/27/14 Nora added z-index because menu was going behind thumbnails
     10/29/14 Nora adjusted size from 290
  */

.well ul li:hover li a
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-shadow: none;
} /* 10/9/14 Nora added to keep green border from showing in dropdown menus 
     10/27/14 Nora added font information
  */

.well ul li:hover li a:hover
{
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
} /* 10/29/14 Nora added to remove green border from 2nd level
  */
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Create a fiddle: jsfiddle.net.